# Why do i get an empty file when trying to edit it using pyhon?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to edit a text file that is html using python. When printing it, it gives an empty file. Why it gets empty? I tried to print it because I don't know how to return it.
*Here's the code:*

```
    import bleach 

    with open ('index1.txt','w') as f: #to open the file that contains html markups
    
            bleach.clean( 
             'f',
             tags=['p'],
             attributes=['style'],
             styles=['color'], 
            )    
    
    f=open('index1.txt')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    print(content)
```

Comment: I think you should `with open("index1.txt")` with out `"w"`?

Answer (score 1):

It becomes empty because you open file for writing with 'w' and thus make it empty as per documentation - just change it to 'r' or 'a'

Comment: If I do that, there is no change in the file. import bleach

Answer (score 0):

It would remain empty because you're just creating a file & not writing anything on it.

Comment: I am trying to edit the file. So how can i do that? in other words, how to return the edited file or print it?

Comment: If you want to edit the file, open it in append mode like `open("index1.txt", "a")`.
If you want to print the file content, open it in read mode like `open("index1.txt", "r")`.